# Contrapositive proof

Tags: linear-algebra

If $A$ is nonsingular and $||\delta A||*||A^{-1}|| < 1$ then $A+ \delta A$ is nonsingular.

Shouldn't the contrapositive be

If $A + \delta A$ is singular then $||\delta A||*||A^{-1}|| \geq 1$ or A is singular.?

The author proves the theorem the following way:

Suppose $A + \delta A$ is singular then $\exists y \neq 0$ such that $(A + \delta A)y =0$

then $Ay + \delta Ay =0 \rightarrow Ay = -\delta Ay $

Right here I get lost, he multiplies by $A^{-1}$, Was that part of the assumption?

$y=  -A^{-1} \delta A y$  etc...

Isn't the contrapostive of
$p \wedge q \rightarrow r$ ==

$\neg r \rightarrow \neg (p \wedge q) \rightarrow \neg p \vee \neg q $

Comment: Contrapositive is relative to a set of unchanged hypotheses. here, I would interpret things as having $A$ nonsingular be a fixed part of the universe, also $\delta$ a real number. With that as background, there is always an $A^{-1}.$ In later studies, when there are a dozen assumptions, usually about ten are part of the background, or the area under study. Wording in advanced texts is often quite loose, and needs care on the part of the reader.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your contrapositive is correct, and the thing to be shown is that, given $A+\delta$ is singular, then *either* $A$ is singular *or* the norm product is at least $1$. Now note that [P or Q] is the same as [(not-P) implies Q], so in proving what you want, you can assume "not-($A$ is singular)" in the proof, and then proceed to attempt to show the norm product is at least 1, and during that one can use that $A$ is nonsingular.